# Copy contents of json file but change the keys based on a list in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

Let's say I have a json file `test.json` as follows and and a list `cities = ['bj', 'wh', 'hz', 'gz']`:

```
{
  "sh_office" : {
    "left" : 12.14,
    "top" : 145.28,
    "width" : 131.73,
    "height" : 94.19
  },
  "sh_retail" : {
    "left" : 199.83,
    "top" : 117.52,
    "width" : 570.67,
    "height" : 253.87
  }
}
```

I would like to append more cities' data by coping contents from `sh_office` and `sh_retail`.

The expected result will be like:

```
{
  "sh_office" : {
    "left" : 12.14,
    "top" : 145.28,
    "width" : 131.73,
    "height" : 94.19
  },
  "sh_retail" : {
    "left" : 199.83,
    "top" : 117.52,
    "width" : 570.67,
    "height" : 253.87
  },
  "bj_office" : {
    "left" : 12.14,
    "top" : 145.28,
    "width" : 131.73,
    "height" : 94.19
  },
  "bj_retail" : {
    "left" : 199.83,
    "top" : 117.52,
    "width" : 570.67,
    "height" : 253.87
  },
  "wh_office" : {
    "left" : 12.14,
    "top" : 145.28,
    "width" : 131.73,
    "height" : 94.19
  },
  "wh_retail" : {
    "left" : 199.83,
    "top" : 117.52,
    "width" : 570.67,
    "height" : 253.87
  },
  ...
}
```

How could I do that in Python? Thanks.

To read json file, I use:

```
import json
f = open('./test.json', "r")
data = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is used `re.sub` for possible specified start of string by `^` for safer replacement of `^sh` to another substrings, last merge original values of `d`:

```
import re

cities = ['bj', 'wh', 'hz', 'gz']
out = {**d, **{re.sub( r'^sh', c, k):v for c in cities for k, v in d.items()}}
```

Another idea without specified starts of `sh`:

```
out = {**d, **{k.replace('sh', c):v for c in cities for k, v in d.items()}}
```

---

```
print (out)
{
'sh_office': {
    'left': 12.14,
    'top': 145.28,
    'width': 131.73,
    'height': 94.19
},
'sh_retail': {
    'left': 199.83,
    'top': 117.52,
    'width': 570.67,
    'height': 253.87
},
'bj_office': {
    'left': 12.14,
    'top': 145.28,
    'width': 131.73,
    'height': 94.19
},
'bj_retail': {
    'left': 199.83,
    'top': 117.52,
    'width': 570.67,
    'height': 253.87
},
'wh_office': {
    'left': 12.14,
    'top': 145.28,
    'width': 131.73,
    'height': 94.19
},
'wh_retail': {
    'left': 199.83,
    'top': 117.52,
    'width': 570.67,
    'height': 253.87
},
'hz_office': {
    'left': 12.14,
    'top': 145.28,
    'width': 131.73,
    'height': 94.19
},
'hz_retail': {
    'left': 199.83,
    'top': 117.52,
    'width': 570.67,
    'height': 253.87
},
'gz_office': {
    'left': 12.14,
    'top': 145.28,
    'width': 131.73,
    'height': 94.19
},
'gz_retail': {
    'left': 199.83,
    'top': 117.52,
    'width': 570.67,
    'height': 253.87
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, if `sh` reappear in `cities` list, it will create duplicated data for `sh`, right?

Comment: @ahbon - No, because dictionary has unique keys.